# How to convert plain html to magento theme?

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to convert plain-html of online-store to magento theme. I know about magento layout and template method but is there any way to do this directly, means you just need to enter plain-html of a page and It will be converted into magento theme structure, or is there any extension which can do that?

Comment: You have to first understand the structure of Magento theme. There is no tool to do so directly.

Comment: I know the structure of Magento theme completely that's why I want the way to do that. If you have any suggestions please share.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you know the structure, you should know how to break it down into theme files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to understand the structure of magento and use designer guide for magento documentation for more information

Comment: #Nikul: Magento theme designer guide is very useful document of Magento Documents. But please tell me if any extension is available or a way to convert html to magento theme directly.